What are tools and lesson do I need to make an AI drone?
Recently, I've been exploring AI drones online, and I've conceptualized an exciting idea: creating an advanced automated AI drone. This drone would be capable of flight controlled through text commands, much like interacting with ChatGPT. Its functionalities would include aerial photography and Image Recognition Additionally, it would be equipped for tasks such as delivering food and parcels to designated recipients which would be fully automated.
As a beginner in this field, I'm eager to learn about the state-of-the-art tools and technologies necessary to realize such a powerful drone.

Is that all? You only need 10+ years experience.
